# Showing Direction Arrow on Line in Mapboxgl

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Trying to show a arrow as indication of direction in mapboxgl. The arrow is only visible at high zoom and is not visible at low zooms.

Adding a image Layer with `'symbol-placement': 'line'`

**Line Layer**

```
  map.addLayer({
          'id': 'route',
          'type': 'line',
          'source': 'mapSource',
          'filter': ['==', '$type', 'LineString'],
          'layout': {
            'line-join': 'round',
            'line-cap': 'round'
          },
          'paint': {
            'line-color': '#3cb2d0',
            'line-width': {
              'base': 1.5,
              'stops': [[1, 0.5], [8, 3], [15, 6], [22, 8]]
            }
          }
        });
```

**Arrow Layer**

```
const url = 'img/arrow.png'
    map.loadImage(url, (err, image) => {
      if (err) { return; }
      map.addImage('arrow', image);
      map.addLayer({
        'id': 'arrowId',
        'type': 'symbol',
        'source': 'mapSource',
        'layout': {
          'symbol-placement': 'line',
          'symbol-spacing': 1,
          'icon-allow-overlap': true,
          // 'icon-ignore-placement': true,
          'icon-image': 'arrow',
          'icon-size': 0.045,
          'visibility': 'visible'
        }
      });
    });
```

**No Arrow at low zoom**

[image]

**Arrow showing at high zoom**

[image]

I have tried experimenting with symbol-spacing, but it didn't work.
Is there way to force mapbox to show arrow on low zoom?

[jsfiddle.net/4jjmh2nb](https://jsfiddle.net/4jjmh2nb)

Comment: Can you put up a JSfiddle so we can play with it?

Comment: @SteveBennettㄹ http://jsfiddle.net/4jjmh2nb/

Comment: Hmm, I don't know. `symbol-spacing` should control this, but it's not having any effect below about 100 or so. I suspect it's related to your source icon being so huge. Maybe resizing the image first, rather than relying on `icon-size`.

Comment: @SteveBennettㄹthanks icon size was the issue

Comment: @vito what did you change icon-size to / how did you change the icon

Comment: @marisbest2 resized the image to 6x6 pixels / reduced image resolution

Comment: Can't figure out from this example - if i am adding a `LineString` DYNAMICALLY to the map feature list, i.e. `polyline = ({ geometry: { type: 'LineString', coordinates: {...} }, properties: {...} }) as mapboxgl.GeoJSON.Feature<mapboxgl.GeoJSON.LineString>; featureCollection.features.push(polyline);` - how to add a predefined arrow to it right away?

Comment: @Alexander, there is no pre defined arrow,  a new img layer needs to added, try the jsfiddle and try to use ur the JWT token

Answer (score 3):

Please use minzoom attribute to set icon at low zoom level. May be it will be helpuful for you. You can adjust the zoom level at and above which you want to display arrow icon.

```js
const url = 'img/arrow.png'
    map.loadImage(url, (err, image) => {
      if (err) { return; }
      map.addImage('arrow', image);
      map.addLayer({
        'id': 'arrowId',
        'type': 'symbol',
        'source': 'mapSource',
        'layout': {
          'symbol-placement': 'line',
          'symbol-spacing': 1,
          'icon-allow-overlap': true,
          // 'icon-ignore-placement': true,
          'icon-image': 'arrow',
          'icon-size': 0.045,
          'visibility': 'visible'
        },
        minzoom: 10,
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Props go to [@Robert Ss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11578082/robert-s) answer.
Just a minor addition on how to add an SVG and why it may not be displayed.

#### Loading a SVG

**Wait for the Image to be loaded**

```js
const arrowSvg = require("@/icons/arrow.svg"); //get the img path
  
const img = new Image(32, 32); //create HTMLElement
img.src = arrowSvg; //set HTMLELement img src
  
img.onload = () => map.addImage("arrow-right", img); //when img is loaded, add it to the map
  
map.addLayer(
{
  "id": "layerId",
  "type": "symbol",
  "source": "mapSourceId",
  "layout": {
    "symbol-placement": "line",
    "symbol-spacing": 25,
    "icon-allow-overlap": true,
    "icon-image": "arrow-right",
    "icon-size": 0.75,
    "visibility": "visible"
  }
}
);
```

Waiting for the image to be loaded is key.

#### Coloring a MapLibre GL SVG symbol layer

Is only possible when using [Signed Distance Fields](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/using-recolorable-images-in-mapbox-maps/#using-sdf-enabled-images)
Enable as follows;

```js
img.onload = () => map.addImage("arrow-right", img, { sdf: true });
```

This will cause `icon-color`, `icon-halo-color`, `icon-halo-width`, and `icon-halo-blur` to work.